# problems uploading .dat file to firebird database with Python

Tags: python, blob, firebird

I wrote some Python code to upload a set of files to my firebird database.
This data set consists out of 3 small text files (1kB) and 1 larger dat file (4MB)
When I store these files in my database the 3 smal text files are ok but the larger dat file is only sorted partially (~400 KB).
When I use my firebird database manager or my own Delphi code uploading the file is not a problem

Please see the code below for the way I upload the files to the database

```
    pname="C:/15530-20160525075425/MeasData"
    gpname="C:/15530-20160525075425"
    fWaveRXPath=pname + '/' + "Waveform-RX.dat"
    fWaveRX = file(fWaveRXPath)
    fConfigPath=gpname + '/' + "Config.ini"
    fConfig = file(fConfigPath)
    fMeasPath=pname + '/' + "meas_cond-RX.txt"
    fMeas = file(fMeasPath)
    fWavePath=pname + '/' + "Waveform.txt"
    fWave = file(fWavePath)

    InsertStatement="insert into Tosh_Probe (PIJPNR, TEKENINGNR, RX_DATA, DATUM,  TIJD,  OPMERKING,  OPERATOR, CONFIG, MEAS_COND, WAVEFORM, ARRAYNR, SERIENR ) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    cur.execute(InsertStatement, (Pijpnr,Tekeningnr, fWaveRX, TestDate, TestTime, "", Operator,fConfig,fMeas,fWave,ArrayNr,Serienr))
    con.commit()
```

So what I basically do is make a pointer to file and use this pointer in my sql statement to fill the variables.

In order to check if my database is capable of handeling such files I wrote some delphi code to update de RX_Data field for a particulary entry with larger dat file

```
    sql:='update TOSH_PROBE set RX_Data=:RX_Data Where Pijpnr = 15530';
    mydBase.query.sql.clear;
    mydBase.query.sql.add(sql);
    mydBase.query.prepare;
    mydbase.query.ParamByName('RX_Data').LoadFromFile('C:\15530-20160525075425\MeasData\Waveform-RX.dat',ftblob);
    mydbase.query.execSql;
    mydbase.query.close;
```

Is there an equivalent way in Python to upload blob files to the database, or are there other ways to overcome this issue

Comment: Are you using kinterbasdb or fdb?  Can you read the contents of the file and pass it?  i.e. fWaveRX = open(fWaveRXPath,'rb').read()

Comment: Did you mean **stored** partially instead of **sorted**?

Comment: I'm using the fdb library. The problem is with storing (opslaan) the blob in the database

Comment: If I look carefully to my code the file open does not specify what kind of file it is so opening it as an binary file might do the trick.

Comment: Opening the file as a binary file did the trick.